# DateTime Object in Python 3.4 - Performing FreeBusy Query Outlook

Tags: python, datetime, outlook

I'm a newb to Python. I'm in the process of porting a lot of my old VBA code to Python.

Here's what I had in VBA:

```
Schedule = myRecipient.FreeBusy(Now(), Duration, True)
```

Calling this FreeBusy method would return a string representing a recipient's availability.

My main problem is getting a valid DateTime to swap in for the Now().

Here's what I've tried most recently:

```
import win32com.client
import tkinter as tk
import time
import pywintypes


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.new = tk.Button(self, text="Outlook", fg="blue",command=self.Connect_Outlook)
        self.new.pack()

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",command=root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.pack(side="bottom")

    def Connect_Outlook(self):
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

        myRecipient = outlook.CreateRecipient("SomeEmailHere")
        now_seconds = time.time ()
        now_pytime = pywintypes.Time (now_seconds)

        print(now_pytime)
        Schedule = myRecipient.FreeBusy(now_pytime, 30)
```

I keep getting this error "ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime". I'm lost, and I'd appreciate some direction on getting this DateTime properly formatted.

Thanks all! :)

Answer (score 1):

The [FreeBusy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869807(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Recipient class accepts the following arguments:

- Start [Date] - The start date for the returned period of free/busy information.
- MinPerChar [Long] - The number of minutes per character represented in the returned free/busy string.

You need to pass a date object instead, for example - `date.today()`.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I tried what you suggested; however I get this error. TypeError: must be a pywintypes time object (got datetime.date). I researched and tried some other options but it didn't work.

Comment: I'd suggest asking Python specialists instead.